# Largest value of the Möbius function for subposet of product of chains

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets, mobius-inversion

Given a product $P$ of chains of lengths $a_1, \dots, a_n$, what is an upper bound on the largest possible value of the absolute value of the Möbius function on a subposet of this poset? Perhaps in terms of $a_1, \dots, a_n$?

For example, one can obtain something like $\min(a_i)^n$ by considering the embedding of this $P$ into $\mathbb Z^n$, with minimum value at $(0, \dots, 0)$ and maximum value at $(a_1-1, \dots, a_n-1)$, and then taking the subposet consisting of the minimum, maximum, and all elements whose components sum to $\min(a_i)$.

Comment: I don't know this in any cases unfortunately. Also, thanks for that reference in the case of boolean algebras, I haven't seen that!

Answer (score 2):

I'm converting my comments to an answer.

Even in the case of a finite Boolean lattice $B_n$ (i.e., with all $a_i=2$), I believe that an exact answer to this question is not known. But it has been studied.

A very relevant reference is “Maximizing Möbius functions on subsets of Boolean algebras” by Sagan, Yeh, and Ziegler (https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(94)90273-9). You might especially be interested in Theorem 1.2 (2) there, which shows how to achieve a subposet of $B_n$ with (absolute value) of Möbius function equal to $E_n$, the [Euler number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_numbers). Euler numbers grow much faster than $2^n$, so this bound is much better than the one you mention in your question.

Two caveats: they focus on absolute value of Möbius function instead of Möbius function, but for half the values of $n$ the Möbius function will be positive, and anyways it should not make a huge difference whether we allow negative values or not. Also, in showing that their constructions are optimal, they focus on particular kinds of subposets. For the Euler number $E_n$, this is the best you can do with "rank-selected" subposets, but it may be possible to do better for other kinds of subposets. However, notice how they say on the 2nd page of their paper "There is some evidence to suspect that the extreme configurations in the case of arbitrary set systems are rank selections as well."

Comment: I'll repeat my comment here. 

Thanks for that reference in the case of boolean algebras, I haven't seen that!

I also edited my question so that it talks about the absolute value of the mobius function, which is actually what I'm interested in.

Comment: Just a note though that I also don't require a sharp upper bound, and I wonder if there are any general upper bounds to the Mobius function that apply here? The only one I've seen was bounding via number of chains, though unfortunately that's not strong enough. It seems to me that most research surrounding these questions are more about fixing a certain class of posets and asking what do posets that maximize mobius function (or whatever function) look like instead of giving a non-sharp upper bound on the functions themselves, which is what I might be more interested in.

Comment: @johng23 Maybe you should clarify in the question that you are looking for *upper* bounds, that was not so clear to me.