# Largest rank-selected Möbius function of a product of chains

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets

Inspired by [this
question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448124) and the answer by Sam Hopkins, given a finite product $P$
of chains, which rank-selection gives the largest absolute value of
the Möbius function? Equivalently, given a finite multiset $M$ of
integers, which set $S$ maximizes the number of permutations of $M$
with descent set $S$? For a product of $n$ two-element chains (the
boolean algebra $B_n$), the answer goes back to Niven and de Bruijn, who
showed that the maximum is achieved by $S=\{1,3,5,\dots\}\cap
\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ and $S=\{2,4,6,\dots\}\cap
\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$.

There is a generalization (comparing Möbius
functions of various rank-selections of $B_n$) in *Enumerative
Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second edition, Proposition 1.6.4. Can this
result be extended to an arbitrary finite product of chains?